# While doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function Sort(td)
{
    var t=document.getElementById("theList");
    var rows=t.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var cells=t.cells;
    var bb=true;
    while(bb==true)
    {
    alert(bb);
      for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
           if(cells[td.cellIndex+i*4].innerText<cells[td.cellIndex+(i+1)*4].innerText)
            {

            }
        }
    alert("Works"); //this alert is not reached
    }
}
```

The second alert will not be shown. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Do you get a javascript error on the page? If the for-loop has an error at some point, the second alert won't fire.

Comment: Probably because script execution terminates somewhere after the first alert and before the second alert. Do you get any error messages in your browser? (Which browser is that?)

Comment: I use Opera. No errors. It works, but WHILE works at once and doesn't return.

Comment: Try web developement kit addon for firefox to track javascript error..
Google it.

Comment: @piemesons: That won't help here, firefox doesn't support `innerText`.

Comment: When do you set `bb` to `false` in your code? There might be a problem with exceeding the *maximum stack size* if you use a `while` loop without terminating it.

Comment: Everything was easy. Dyring the last iteration the function tryed to compare not existing item)

Answer (score 2):

Your `var rows` is an array, which will not have a property "cells". That could be your problem right there.

Comment: +1. Also wondering if it should be `var rows=t.getElementsByTagName("tr");` rather than `td`

Comment: @Martin Smith: hmm... that sounds suspiciously like it makes too much sense.

Comment: @Martin: Probably right. I sense what he is trying to do, but I just wouldn't do this the same way. I'd probably use nested for loops instead of a while. I almost *never* use a while loop, if I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong in any of the code in the for loop it won't reach the second alert. I'd suggest running this in a JS debugger.